# PHP: need more decimal places for sinus calculation

Tags: php, mysql, math, decimal, radians

to calculate some longitude and latitude values I need more decimal places like mysql is possible to do.

For instance with mysql I get this result:

```
cos( RADIANS( 47.685618 ) ) = 0.67319814951254
```

With PHP 5.2 I only get:

```
cos( deg2rad( 47.685618 ) ) = 0.673198149513
```

Two decimal places shorter but I need them.

I know I also can do the calulation with mysql, but in my case it need to be done with PHP.

I hope you can help me? Thx.

Comment: How many centimeters accuracy do you really need?  I bet if you calculate the difference in position between calculations done with 12 digits of precision versus calculations done with 14 digits of precision, you'll find the difference is less than the accuracy of the original locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The precision directive can be changed (see [BYTES.com](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/759136-changing-precision-level-floating-point-variables)).

2nd result for Google: *php precision float*.

Comment: Answers that rely entirely on outside resources are unhelpful (in case the outside resource moves or goes away.)